# Jenkins Pipeline Build Error -> Test Report Files not found

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin, build-error

I receive the following error message when trying to make a build with Jenkins Pipeline. It says that it cannot find the report files. But according to my understanding should these report files not be generated while executing the tests? Locally I can run the tests with mvnw clear test and the files are generated in the target folder (Maven Project). As the target folder contains build files, I dont assume that I have to upload these files to the git Repo? 
For any kind of help, I would be very happy!

Jenking Build Failure:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/tool Job/workspace/target/surefire/surefirebooter1117922841156378420.jar

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.507 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-07T15:21:53Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 58M/398M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project j-hipster-irp: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/tool Job/workspace" && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/bin/java '-javaagent:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.9/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/tool Job/workspace/target/test-results/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec' -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m -jar '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/tool Job/workspace/target/surefire/surefirebooter1117922841156378420.jar' '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/tool Job/workspace/target/surefire/surefire1734872125374791310tmp' '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/tool Job/workspace/target/surefire/surefire_03108578491450238058tmp'
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[Pipeline] junit
Recording test results
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE
```

The Jenkinsfile contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node {
    stage('checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }

    stage('check java') {
        sh "java -version"
    }

    stage('clean') {
        sh "chmod +x mvnw"
        sh "./mvnw clean"
    }

    stage('install tools') {
        sh "./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:install-node-and-yarn -DnodeVersion=v6.11.3 -DyarnVersion=v1.1.0"
    }

    stage('yarn install') {
        sh "./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:yarn"
    }

    stage('backend tests') {
        try {
            sh "./mvnw test"
        } catch(err) {
            throw err
        } finally {
            junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
        }
    }

    stage('frontend tests') {
        try {
            sh "./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:yarn -Dfrontend.yarn.arguments=test"
        } catch(err) {
            throw err
        } finally {
            junit '**/target/test-results/karma/TESTS-*.xml'
        }
    }

    stage('packaging') {
        sh "./mvnw package -Pprod -DskipTests"
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.war', fingerprint: true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [JUnit Jenkins plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/junit/) has a flag to allow empty test results:

> `allowEmptyResults` (optional)
>   If checked, the default behavior of failing a build on missing test result files or empty test results is changed to not affect the status of the build. Please note that this setting make it harder to spot misconfigured jobs or build failures where the test tool does not exit with an error code when not producing test report files.